# g++ fatal error: killed signal terminated program cc1plus when trying to install NS3 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ns-3

I'm trying to install ns3 version 3.32 in my ubuntu 20.04 LTS (using oracle virtualbox). I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev python3-pygraphviz cvs mercurial bzr git cmake p7zip-full python3-matplotlib python-tk python3-dev qt5-qmake qt-default gnuplot-x11 wireshark
tar jxvf ns-allinone-3.32.tar.bz2
cd ns-allinone-3.32/
./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests
```

After that build command it started compiling a lot of files. Then it took an especially long time on [2431/2878] compilation, then I got this error:

`g++: fatal error: killed signal terminated program cc1plus`

`compilation terminated`

I tried again and again but it always stop there. I don't know what's wrong. I already gave 100gb storage to ubuntu and it has 2 processors and 2048mb base memory.

Comment: This is likely an OOM error. Try allocating more memory to your VM.

Answer (score 11):

Can confirm, I have been installing ns3 V3.33 and around [2447/2973] compilation this error came out.

For the solution I doubled the base memory of my VM (2048mb -> 4096mb), then the compilation finished successfully.